# How can I toggle a astable 555?

Tags: infrared, 555, modulation

I'm using a NE555 running at 37KHz to generate a carrier frequency for transmitting IR.

Now I need to modulate it using OOK, I know that are various ways to toggle it.
The most obvious way is to toggle the output using a transistor, but I don't quite like the ideia of let it running the whole time, considering it will be most of the time sitting idle.

And I don't know if toggling Vcc would work, I don't know if it oscillate right on, and it will requite a PNP switching transistor rather than a signal transistor.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to simply use an AND (or OR) gate with one input from the '555 output and one from your ENABLE signal.

If you try switch the 555's power on and off for each transmitted symbol, you could have a couple of problems: 1. Switching could be slow because the power bypass capacitors have to charge up and down as you switch. 2. As the power ramps up and down the 555 might produce pulses with wrong duty cycle or wrong frequency.

If you want to save power, you could power the whole transmitter subsystem on and off on a message-by-message basis.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a *long* time since I used a 555 for anything (an 8-pin MCU like a PIC12F or 10F makes far more sense these days imho), but perhaps you could use the /RST pin as a modulation input.